# How can I change this model for multiple choice answer?

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, django-orm

I am making a **Django** app for **multiple choice question-answer** exam. I have created a **Question model** as below.

```
    class Question(models.Model):
        subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        question_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        option1 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        option2 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        option3 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        option4 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        
        answer = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.question_name
```

It is working fine, but now I want to change it so that question can have **more that one option as correct answer**. How can I achieve it?

I will be adding the questions for my app from **admin panel**.
I want to add quesion , their options and then mark the right answer/answers (it is possible to) *otherwise* make a field that can hold the right answer/answers

Is there any way to make a field both CharField and BooleanField ?
Or what approach should I take to complete my goal ?

*Thanks in advance for the suggestions*!!  **:)**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by having two tables, so one `Question` and another for `Option` and then link them via a many to many relationship. Refer to the code below:

```
class Option(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

class Question(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Option, blank=True)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_name
```

This can get you started in the right direction, of course you can make any edits to suit your needs.

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for the suggestion. 
Yes, this approach can achieve my goal. but by this approach I think there will be many unnecessary choices for the question. If I have added 20 questions and all questions have four options. Then there will be way to many unnecessary choices for the options of next new question. Please correct me if I am wrong. As I am very new to Django or coding I might be wrong.Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use the possibilities offered by a relational database and the Django ORM : you could define a Question Model for handling a question, and a Option Model, for handling each choice of each question.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

class Option(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    is_answer = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="True if this choice is the answer of the question")
```

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for the suggestion. I had come around this approach. For this approach I will have to add options four times for each questions (as I am going to give four option choices). So, I think there must be another more efficient way. 

Thanks again.